# How can I combine ImageDataGenerator with TensorFlow datasets in TF2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a TF dataset to [classify](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning) cats and dogs:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
SPLIT_WEIGHTS = (8, 1, 1)
splits = tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(weighted=SPLIT_WEIGHTS)

(raw_train, raw_validation, raw_test), metadata = tfds.load(
    'cats_vs_dogs', split=list(splits),
    with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
```

In the example they use some image augmentation with a map function. I was wondering if that could also be done with the nice `ImageDataGenerator` class such as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification):

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) # Generator for our training data
train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           directory=train_dir,
                                                           shuffle=True,
                                                           target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                           class_mode='binary')
```

The problem I'm facing is that I can only see [3 ways](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) to use the `ImageDataGenerator`: pandas dataframe, numpy array and directory of images. 
Is there any way to also use a Tensorflow dataset and combine these methods?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is but it's a bit tricky.
Keras `ImageDataGenerator` works on `numpy.array`s and not on `tf.Tensor`'s so we have to use Tensorflow's [numpy_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function?version=stable). This will allow us to perform operations on `tf.data.Dataset` content just like it was numpy arrays.

First, let's declare the function that we will `.map` over our dataset (assuming your dataset consists of image, label pairs):

```py
# We will take 1 original image and create 5 augmented images:
HOW_MANY_TO_AUGMENT = 5

def augment(image, label):

  # Create generator and fit it to an image
  img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
  img_gen.fit(image)

  # We want to keep original image and label
  img_results = [(image/255.).astype(np.float32)] 
  label_results = [label]

  # Perform augmentation and keep the labels
  augmented_images = [next(img_gen.flow(image)) for _ in range(HOW_MANY_TO_AUGMENT)]
  labels = [label for _ in range(HOW_MANY_TO_AUGMENT)]

  # Append augmented data and labels to original data
  img_results.extend(augmented_images)
  label_results.extend(labels)

  return img_results, label_results
```

Now, in order to use this function inside `tf.data.Dataset` we must declare a `numpy_function`:

```py
def py_augment(image, label):
  func = tf.numpy_function(augment, [image, label], [tf.float32, tf.int32])
  return func
```

`py_augment` can be safely used like:

`augmented_dataset_ds = image_label_dataset.map(py_augment)`

The `image` part in dataset is now in shape 
`(HOW_MANY_TO_AUGMENT, image_height, image_width, channels)`. 
To convert it to simple `(1, image_height, image_width, channels)` you can simply use `unbatch`:

`unbatched_augmented_dataset_ds = augmented_dataset_ds.unbatch()`

So the entire section looks like this:

```py
HOW_MANY_TO_AUGMENT = 5

def augment(image, label):

  # Create generator and fit it to an image
  img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
  img_gen.fit(image)

  # We want to keep original image and label
  img_results = [(image/255.).astype(np.float32)] 
  label_results = [label]

  # Perform augmentation and keep the labels
  augmented_images = [next(img_gen.flow(image)) for _ in range(HOW_MANY_TO_AUGMENT)]
  labels = [label for _ in range(HOW_MANY_TO_AUGMENT)]

  # Append augmented data and labels to original data
  img_results.extend(augmented_images)
  label_results.extend(labels)

  return img_results, label_results

def py_augment(image, label):
  func = tf.numpy_function(augment, [image, label], [tf.float32, tf.int32])
  return func

unbatched_augmented_dataset_ds = augmented_dataset_ds.map(py_augment).unbatch()

# Iterate over the dataset for preview:
for image, label in unbatched_augmented_dataset_ds:
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

One idea is you could create a generator wrapper function that uses your tfds Dataset to load multiples of your batch size. Then pass those images, labels to ImageDataGenerator's flow method which would yield augmented data at a rate of your desired batch size.

For example:

```
def tfds_imgen(ds, imgen, batch_size, batches_per):
    for images, labels in ds:
        flow_ = imgen.flow(images, labels, batch_size=batch_size)
        for _ in range(batches_per):
            yield next(flow_)

raw_train_ds = tfds.load(
    'cats_vs_dogs', split='train',
    batch_size=SOME_MULTIPLE_OF_32,
    as_supervised=True)

imgen = ImageDataGenerator(...)

train_ds = tfds_imgen(
    raw_train_ds.as_numpy_iterator(), imgen,
    batch_size=32, batches_per=SOME_MULTIPLE_OF_32 // 32)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to add the data augmentation via keras preprocessing layers, making the augmentation part of your model (see here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation#data_augmentation_2).

Example from the docs:

```py
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),
  layers.RandomRotation(0.2),
])
```